# How to send data when change in existing db.json using slices and RTK API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

When I create new invoice then a edit page open and we can edit here, when editing the slices is updating, now I want that when I press preview then the slices get saved in db.json using `useRecordPaymentMutation`. but its giving me error of 500 status in network.
Here is API and reducers:

```
const invoiceApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "invoice",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
  }),
  endpoints(builder) {
    return {
      fetchInvoice: builder.query({
        query: (id) => {
          return {
            url: id ? `/invoices/${id}` : "/invoices",
            method: "GET",
            // params: id,
          };
        },
      }),
      recordPayment: builder.mutation({
        invalidatesTags: ["invoice"],
        query: (body) => {
          return {
            url: "/invoices",
            method: "POST",
            body,
          };
        },
      }),
    };
  },
});

 createNewInvoice(state,action){
       state = action.payload;
    }
```

and here is button function and invoice is restructured from `useSelector`. Now there are two questions:

1. when I refresh then a new slice is created.
2. when I press button then it get me error for mutating the existing database invoice.

```
 const handlePreview = () => {
     recordPayment(invoice);
     console.log("consoleinvoice",invoice)
  };
```

I have tried changing the API, like use / before invoices. I think we have to pass id or something like that so that it can recognize which invoice we should change. How to do this?